plymouth cannnot work normally with graphic theme
Here is a gentoo-kernel(6.11.3) with openrc(0.55.1)+elogind(255.5) and dracut(103-r4)+grub(2.12-r5) operating system. plymouth version is 22.02.122-r2
Hardware: amd64, nvidia
Plymouth can not work smoothly to start sddm with any graphic theme, configration wiht graphic theme will spalsh or flash the animation over and over again, but sddm is not be there as it should. Only "details" theme could work normally, but as you all known, this theme is not a graphic theme.
I noticed that the publisher of Plymouth in gitlab announced that Plymouth do not support to build from source code, caused by it's relative to distro.
And I noticed that current version of plymouth in gentoo repository with a timestamp in 2022, and current version in gitlab with timestamp 2024, I'm not sure whether what I'm encountered is relative to the version difference.

sys-boot/plymouth-openrc-plugin is emerged and  the rc_interactive=false in rc.conf before I encountered the graphic problem
